# Is this an error by my lecturer? Closure definition

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

My lecturer defined the closure of a set $M$ to be $\overline{M}=\bigcap \{ F \mid F$ is closed and $F\supseteq M \}$.

However, in other modules it has been defined as $\overline{M}=\bigcap\limits_{F closed, F\supseteq M} F$.

Looking online I see mainly the second version. Is the first one actually correct or a mistake on the lecturers part? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are the same definition; just different notation.

Comment: Do you understand what each of these notations mean?

Comment: Oh. I assumed the first one meant the intersections of $\{F_1\},\{F_2\}$... etc. Thanks for clearing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both formulas say that

> The closure of $M$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $M$.

As closure of any set always exists, it means exactly that $\bar M$ is the *smallest* closed subset that contains $M$. And, eventually it contains the points and the limit points of $M$.